# Check particular value is set or not in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, spring-security

I have a multi user portal where I am storing a value in `securedHolder` for two users (admin and teacher). But not storing the value for super admin.

I have to display the navigation menu as per the user role (admin, teacher and super admin).

So I want to check the value is set or not in JSP page. How to do it in JSP?

I have checked the user role but not able to check the particular value.

```
 <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_TEACHER')">
        -- Do something for teacher
        -- want to check the value here 
 </sec:authorize>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not save the role attribute in your user session as "teacher", "admin", or "superadmin" whenever a user logins?

Then you can do something like this using jstl tag:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${sessionScope.user.role == 'teacher'}">
        your nav bar for teachers
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${sessionScope.user.role == 'admin'}">
        your nav bar for admins
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${sessionScope.user.role == 'superadmin'}">
        your nav bar for superadmins
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        your nav bar for somebody else
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: Then you can just add whatever you are distinguishing a super admin with from everything else, as a model attribute in your controller. And check that using the `<c:when test=...>` tag.

Comment: The role is already at session inside the `Authentication` object, managed by `spring-security`. There is no need to do this

Comment: thanx for the response but i have done by using <sec:authorize access="principal.securedHolder['value']==1"></sec:authorize>

Answer (score 0):

Do it using `jstl` this way:

```
<c:if test="${not empty var}">
   <div>do whatever you need</div>  
</c:if>
```

Mixing all, I'll do it like this:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_TEACHER','ROLE_ADMIN')">
    <c:if test="${not empty var}">
       <div>do whatever you need</div>  
    </c:if>
 </sec:authorize>
```

Comment: thanx for the response but i have done by using <sec:authorize access="principal.securedHolder['value']==1"></sec:authorize>

Answer (score 0):

Done by using
`<sec:authorize access="principal.securedHolder['value']==requiredvalue"></sec:authorize>`